# xampp not loading image

Tags: php, image, xampp, serve

Image not loading in xammp package.

My apache virtual hosts config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\shop.local"
    ServerName shop.local
    ErrorLog "logs/shop.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/shop.local-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Structure of my directory:

```
 - public
   - .htaccess
   - index.php
   - errors
     - 404.php
     - images
       - 404.png
 - vendor
 - .htaccess
```

htaccess in root dir:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

htaccess in public dir:

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php file:

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/public/errors/404.php';
```

404.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="/errors/images/404.png">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Apache logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Sep/2019:01:35:14 +0300] "GET /public/errors/404.png HTTP/1.1" 200 141
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: Path is `/error/` not `/errors/` . I hope it's not a typo in the question post again

Comment: Path is /errors/.It is my mistake in writting question.I am not getting any specific errors.I have added apache logs.

Answer (score 0):

I just write wrong condition in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
```

Properly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```